# Как передать сomputed в data при использовании плагина Vue-Table-2

Tags: vue.js

Создаю таблицу на плагине [Vue-Table-2](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2). У меня есть JSON, данные из которого я преобразую через вычислемые свойства и на выходе получаю новый массив данных. Этот новый массив мне и нужно передать в таблицу. Однако у меня не выходит это релаизовать, массив dataResult остается пустым.

```js
    <v-client-table :data="dataResult" :columns="columns" :options="options"></v-client-table>

    export default {  
      name: "teams_table", 
      data () {
       return {
         columns: ['team_name','matches','scored', 'missed', 'diff'],
         dataResult: [],//сюда мне нужно передать данные из вычисляемых свойств
         options: {
              headings: {
                team_name: 'Team',
                matches: 'Matches',
                scored: 'Goals (scored)',
                missed: 'Goals (missed)',
                diff: 'Differ'
              },    
        }
      },
      computed: {   
         teamsStats() {             
           var data = this.filteredMatches();
           var arr = []; 
           var scored = []; 
           var missed = []; 
           var diff = [];  
           var game = {};   

                function() { 
                  for (var i in data) { 
                        //здесь много кода для обработки данных, полученных из JSON через this.filteredMatches();
                        //...
                      };
                  }; 

               //Тут я создаю новый массив, который хочу передать в data плагин Vue-Table-2
                Object.keys(game).forEach(function(el, data) {
                      arr.push( [ el, game[el], scored[el], missed[el], diff[el] ] );                    
                  });                          
               }; 
              var result = arr.map(([team_name, matches, scored, missed, diff]) => ({team_name, matches, scored, missed, diff})); 
              return result;           
           },
```

Если я помещаю данные непосредственно в `dataResult`, все работает.

```js
    data () {
    dataResult:  [
        {team_name: "Team1", matches: 3, scored: 3, missed: 7, diff: 1},
        {team_name: "Team2", matches: 3, scored: 7, missed: 3, diff: 1},
        {team_name: "Team3", matches: 1, scored: 1, missed: 1, diff: 1},
    ],
    }
```

Но мне-то нужно передать туда данных из `computed`. Я пыталась сделать это через `mounted()`, но тоже не сработало - массив dataResult остается пустым.

```js
    mounted(){
        this.dataResult = this.teamsStats
     }
```

Был предложен еще вот такой вариант, через `slot` плагина. Однако он тоже не сработал, мне все равно нужно сначала как-то вывести teamsStats в dataResult, а как раз это и не получается.

```
<v-client-table :data="dataResult" :columns="columns" :options="options">
    <div slot="scored" slot-scope="data">
         {{this.teamsStats.scored}}
    </div>
    ...
</v-client-table>
```

**UPD.** Проблема решена заменой вызова `dataResult` на `teamsStats` непосредственно в вызове таблицы.

```
 <v-client-table :data="teamsStats" :columns="columns" :options="options">      
 </v-client-table>
```

Comment: прекрепите ссылку на плагнин

Comment: попробуйте передать в таблицу не `dataResult `, а `teamsStats`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это сработало!